# Confusing with call back in node js

Tags: node.js

I have this query in nodejs. Please modify the code such a way that it will query database for each iteration and store each time result in result array.
and it will be send to my callback function after for loop execution finished.When i am trying place callback(result) after result.push(data) it works but it will send nearly rows.length times because of for loop.

function query_database(req,callback){
    result=[];

```
class_code=req.body.class;
branch=req.body.branch;
year=req.body.year;
start_date=req.body.start_date;
end_date=req.body.end_date;
flag=false;
query='select id,rollno from student where branch="'+branch+'" and class="'+class_code+'" and year="'+year+'"';

//console.log(query);
connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err){
        query_total_working_days(start_date,end_date,branch,class_code,year,function(err,data){
            if(err){

            }
            else{
                total_days=data;
                for(index=0;index<rows.length;index++){
                    query_attendance(rows[index].id,rows[index].rollno,start_date,end_date,total_days,function(err,data){
                        if(err){

                        }
                        else{
                            result.push(data)
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        })
        callback(null,result)

    }

    else
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});
```

}

Comment: can your provide your requires/imports?

Comment: i didn't get you buddy

Answer (score 1):

### 1. If`query_attence` is synchrone...

this should do the job.

```
/* global req, connection, query_total_working_days, query_attendance, callback */

// assuming req is a correct request.
var class_code = req.body.class,
    branch = req.body.branch,
    year = req.body.year,
    start_date = req.body.start_date,
    end_date = req.body.end_date,
    // this `flag` is never used, why ?? you can remove it.
    flag = false,
    // assuming this is a query that represent a correct SQL query
    query = 'select id,rollno from student where branch="' + branch + '" and class="' + class_code + '" and year="' + year + '"';

// assuming connection is a correct sql connection object
// fields is never used, you can remove it.
connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    }

    // assuming query_total_working_days is a correct « async » function.
    query_total_working_days(start_date, end_date, branch, class_code, year, function(err, data) {
        var total_days,
            result = [],
            index,
            next = function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return ; // you should provide a code for this error.
                }

                // result is not declared, initially. So I create it above.
                result.push(data);
            };

        if (err) {
            return ; // you should provide a code for this error
        }

        total_days = data;

        // assuming query_attendance is a correct « sync » function.
        for (index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
            // I move the `next` callback not it this loop because expression function should not be declared in loop.
            query_attendance(rows[index].id, rows[index].rollno, start_date, end_date, total_days, next);
        }

        // assuming callback is a correct function.
        callback(null, result);
    });
});
```

### 2. But If`query_attence` is asynchrone (probably)

your problem is : `callback` will be executed before all `query_attendance` are finish. So your `result` array will not contain all entry you want.

So in this case. You should use the module `async` for exemple https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md

If order of your result is important, use it in `series`.

If order of your result isn't important, for more speed, use it in `parallele`

```
/* global req, connection, query_total_working_days, query_attendance, callback, async */

// assuming req is a correct request.
var class_code = req.body.class,
    branch = req.body.branch,
    year = req.body.year,
    start_date = req.body.start_date,
    end_date = req.body.end_date,
    // this `flag` is never used, why ?? you can remove it.
    flag = false,
    // assuming this is a query that represent a correct SQL query
    query = 'select id,rollno from student where branch="' + branch + '" and class="' + class_code + '" and year="' + year + '"';

// assuming connection is a correct sql connection object
connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    // fields is never used, you can remove it.
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    }

    // assuming query_total_working_days is a correct « async » function.
    query_total_working_days(start_date, end_date, branch, class_code, year, function(err, data) {
        var total_days,
            parallels = [],
            next = function (next) {
                query_attendance(rows[index].id, rows[index].rollno, start_date, end_date, total_days, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        return ; // you should provide a code for this error 
                    }

                    // result is not declared, initially. So I create it.
                    next(null, data);
                });
            };

        if (err) {
            return ; // you should provide a code for this error
        }

        total_days = data;

        // assuming query_attendance is a correct « async » function.
        // we use let to not set value to variable objet in order to kept the current value of `index` for each call of `next`.
        for (let index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
            parallels.push(next);
        }

        // assuming async is the async npm module. In this case, result order have no importance.
        async.parallel(parallels, function (results) {
            // assuming callback is a correct function.
            callback(null, results);
        });
    });
});
```

NOTE : I am not able to test this code so, say me if you have some error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code maybe simplify like this:

```
function query_database(callback) {
  let result = [];
  query_all(function(rows) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      query_row(rows[i], function (data) {
        result.push(data); // (2)
      }); 
    }
  })
  callback(result); // (1)
}
```

The problem is you can't be sure that (2) is finished before (1). Actually, (1) is called before all (2) can be called.

To make it correct, you need to change to following code:

```
function queryDatabase(callback) {
  let result = [];
  queryAll(function(rows) {
    let i = 0;
    let rowCallBack = function (data) {
      result.push(data);
      i++;
      if (i == rows.length) {
        callback(result);      
      } else {

        queryRow(row[i], rowCallBack);
      }
    };

    queryRow(row[i], rowCallBack);
  })
  callback(result); // (1)
}
```